# How to manually call the js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does the below js function automatically being called when the html loads?
How can I manually call it? (using event or click)

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#divId").load("http://google.com"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="divId" style="display:none;"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: put script in body tag it will automatically run

Comment: F.Y.I. XMLHttpRequest cannot load **http://google.com/**. No '_Access-Control-Allow-Origin_' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: use an iframe, most of site allow it but not google. To get access to content of external page, you need to proxify it server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
        $('#btn').on('click', function() {
            $("#divId").load("http://google.com", function() {
                $(this).show(); // it's display:none ?
            }); 
        });
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <button id="btn">click to load</button>
     <div id="divId" style="display:none;"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Note that loading Google won't work due to the same origin policy and Google's headers.

Comment: seems not to work. I edited to - `$("#divId").load("http://en.wikipedia.org");` but can't see any update on the div. I'm missing something?

Comment: @yonan2236 You can't load content from external websites unless they've specifically allowed it (most have not). You need to load a local file.

Comment: @yonan2236 - as noted in my answer and by Juhana, you can **not** load external sites with javascript due to the same origin policy, you have to load a local file on the same domain as your website.

Answer (score 0):

**When document is ready:**

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#divId").load("http://google.com"); <!-- I don't know what you are trying to do here? -->
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="divId" style="display:none;"></div>
</body>
```

**On a click**

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#divId").load("http://google.com"); <!-- Load Google won't work -->
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<li class="button"><a href="#">Load</a></li>
<div id="divId" style="display:none;"></div>
</body>
```